# component state doesnt change even after replacing data

Tags: reactjs

My image component displays images with a heart over it every time a user submits a search. The heart changes colors if the image is clicked, and should reset to white (default color) when user submits a new search. For some reason, the clicked-color persists even after a search. What am I not understanding about react states? This isn't simply something that changes on the next render. It just stays like that until I change it manually.

```
const Image = ({image, toggleFav, initialIcon, initialAlt}) => {
  const [fav, setFav] = useState(false);
  const [heartIcon, setHeartIcon] = useState(initialIcon)
  const [heartAlt, setHeartAlt] = useState(initialAlt)
  const handleClick = () => {
    setFav(fav => !fav);
    toggleFav(image.id, fav);
    if (heartIcon == "whiteHeartIcon") {
      setHeartIcon("redHeartIcon")
    }
    else {
      setHeartIcon("whiteHeartIcon")
    }
    if (heartAlt == "white heart icon") {
      setHeartAlt("red heart icon")
    }
    else {
      setHeartAlt("white heart icon")
    }
  };
  return (
    <Grid item xs={4} key={image.id}>
      <div className={`${fav ? "fav" : ""}`} onClick={handleClick}>
        <div className="imgBox">
          <img src={image.url} className="image"/>
          <Heart icon={heartIcon} alt={heartAlt} className="heart"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

This is the handle submit func for the component:

```
const searchAllImages = async (keyword) => {
    const response = await searchImages(keyword);
    const imageObjects = response.data.message.map((link, index) => {
      let newImage = {
        url: link,
        id: link,
        fav: false
      };
      return newImage;
    });
    dispatch({type: 'SET_IMAGES', payload: imageObjects});
  };
```

I render the images through a redux store where it replaces the image state every time a new search is done. The state resides in Store.js where image is initially set to an empty list. The dispatch method comes from Reducer.js where the method is defined.

```
case "SET_IMAGES":
      return {
        ...state,
        images: action.payload
      }
```

Comment: you are not setting state in searchAllimages.

Comment: Maybe try [lifting up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or [use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), since these are two different components?

Comment: Where is `searchAllImages` used in relation to the first snippet? Is it from an entirely *different* component? How do these two snippets relate to one another? From what I can tell, `Image` has its own state and that's it, hence the persistence. What are you expecting to happen when `searchAllImages` is called? Can you provide more context?

Comment: @JohnLobo so I assume that when the dispatch method is called it resets the image list, which then requires a re-rendering of the img div and in turn re-renders (resets) the heart components to their default which is white. is this wrong?

Comment: @DrewReese please see my comment above. the Image component gets image list passed in which comes from the dispatch method in searchAllImages

Comment: @ShreyasJadhav so each image component has it's own heart-icon-color state, do you know how i might be able to control those?

Comment: I don't follow, your one comment above has no mention of `searchAllImages`. The `dispatch` method only dispatches an action object to the redux store, it's up to the reducer what it does to the redux state. No local component will be effected by any change to redux state. If you want local state to do something as well you'll need to code that yourself, either in the callback that triggers the action dispatch, or in an `useEffect` in response to when the redux state updates.

Comment: @DrewReese so when images is reset to a new list of images (after a search), this list is passed to the Image component. it's then displayed at the <img src> tag, but right under that is the heart component at which I expect to change every time the img src tag changes. how can i control this with useEffect?

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you render out the array of images from redux state, and where the search state resides and is dispatched from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233188/discussion-between-chadlei-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the initial image to a different variable initially, then use a useEffect that checks the image variable for changes, and if it changes assign the value to the variable mentioned above. Anyways more like using useEffect or useCallback for actions.